# R function that can handle error and warning at once, not one at a time

Tags: r, function, error-handling

My function takes in Event and EventType. If the user does not specify the EventType then code is supposed to figure out the EventType by trying each eventype and pick the one that does not return error or warning since wrong EventType would return either a warning or error.

The issue is I am not able to handle the warning and error at the sametime. With the tryCatch function I can check for error and then if no error, I would have to check again for warning and if no warning and do this until I find EventType that does not return any error or warning. The problem is I have to check for both warning and error at the sametime, not just one.

Here is my code:

```
library(Capr)
cohort_entry <- function(IndexEventType = NA_character_,
                         IndexEvent){
  
  if(is.na(IndexEventType)) {
    e <- tryCatch(expr = condition(IndexEvent),
             error = function(e) {
               tryCatch(expr = condition(IndexEvent),
                        warning = function (w) {
                          tryCatch(expr = procedure(IndexEvent),
                                   error = function(e) {
                                     tryCatch(expr = procedure(IndexEvent),
                                              warning= function(w) {
                                                tryCatch(expr = visit(IndexEvent),
                                                         error = function(e) {
                                                           tryCatch(expr = visit(IndexEvent),
                                                                    warning = function(w) {
                                                                      tryCatch(expr = drug(IndexEvent),
                                                                               error = function(e) {
                                                                                 tryCatch(expr = drug(IndexEvent),
                                                                                          warning = function(w) {
                                                                                            finally = print("No Index Event Found")
                                                                                          })
                                                                               })
                                                                    })
                                                         })
                                              })
                                   })
                        })
             })
  } else {
    IndexEventType = as.character(IndexEventType)
    
    validDomains <- c("conditionEra",
                      "condition",
                      "death",
                      "drug",
                      "drugEra",
                      "measurement",
                      "observation",
                      "visit")
    
    stopifnot(IndexEventType %in% validDomains)
    
    e <- match.fun(IndexEventType)(conceptSet = IndexEvent)
  }
  
  e1 <- entry(e)

}




## Data

c1 <-new("ConceptSet", id = "fa773477eb0c08e1b8d6c7fca590ec21", Name = "QF - Inpatient or Inpatient/ER visit", 
    Expression = list(new("ConceptSetItem", Concept = new("Concept", 
                                                          concept_id = 262L, concept_name = "Emergency Room and Inpatient Visit", 
                                                          standard_concept = "S", standard_concept_caption = "Standard", 
                                                          invalid_reason = "V", invalid_reason_caption = "Valid", 
                                                          concept_code = "ERIP", domain_id = "Visit", vocabulary_id = "Visit", 
                                                          concept_class_id = "Visit"), isExcluded = FALSE, includeDescendants = TRUE, 
                          includeMapped = FALSE), new("ConceptSetItem", Concept = new("Concept", 
                                                                                      concept_id = 8717L, concept_name = "Inpatient Hospital", 
                                                                                      standard_concept = "S", standard_concept_caption = "Standard", 
                                                                                      invalid_reason = "V", invalid_reason_caption = "Valid", 
                                                                                      concept_code = "21", domain_id = "Visit", vocabulary_id = "CMS Place of Service", 
                                                                                      concept_class_id = "Visit"), isExcluded = FALSE, includeDescendants = TRUE, 
                                                      includeMapped = FALSE), new("ConceptSetItem", Concept = new("Concept", 
                                                                                                                  concept_id = 9201L, concept_name = "Inpatient Visit", 
                                                                                                                  standard_concept = "S", standard_concept_caption = "Standard", 
                                                                                                                  invalid_reason = "V", invalid_reason_caption = "Valid", 
                                                                                                                  concept_code = "IP", domain_id = "Visit", vocabulary_id = "Visit", 
                                                                                                                  concept_class_id = "Visit"), isExcluded = FALSE, includeDescendants = TRUE, 
                                                                                  includeMapped = FALSE)))

# c1 is visit EventType

ce1 <- cohort_entry(IndexEvent = c1, IndexEventType = "visit")
ce1@entryEvents[[1]]@domain

ce2 <- cohort_entry(IndexEvent = c1) # when IndexEventType not passed it picked the wrong EventType since it returned warning, not error
ce2@entryEvents[[1]]@domain 

# There are several EventTypes

condition(c1)
drug(c1)
procedure(c1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `tryCatch(expr, warning=function(w) ..., error=function(e) ...)`, simultaneous warning/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a list of strings and evaluate them individually?

Simulation of various processes:

```r
fun1 <- function() {
  rand <- runif(2)
  if (rand[1] < 0.4) stop("fun1 error")
  if (rand[2] < 0.4) warning("fun1 warn")
  TRUE
}

fun2 <- function() {
  rand <- runif(2)
  if (rand[1] < 0.4) stop("fun2 error")
  if (rand[2] < 0.4) warning("fun2 warn")
  TRUE
}

fun3 <- function() {
  rand <- runif(2)
  if (rand[1] < 0.4) stop("fun3 error")
  if (rand[2] < 0.4) warning("fun3 warn")
  TRUE
}
```

Define the various options as strings:

```r
exprs <- c("fun1()", "fun2()", "fun3()")
```

(I'm sure this can be done with expressions or perhaps rlang-style `~`-functions.)

From here, a simple loop that only goes as long as needed:

```r
set.seed(527575)
for (expr in exprs) {
  res <- tryCatch(eval(parse(text = expr)),
                  error = function(e) e,
                  warning = function(w) w)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    message("erred: ", expr)
  } else if (inherits(res, "warning")) {
    message("warned: ", expr)
  } else {
    message("success!: ", expr)
    break
  }
}
# success!: fun1()
set.seed(124413)
for (expr in exprs) {
  res <- tryCatch(eval(parse(text = expr)),
                  error = function(e) e,
                  warning = function(w) w)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    message("erred: ", expr)
  } else if (inherits(res, "warning")) {
    message("warned: ", expr)
  } else {
    message("success!: ", expr)
    break
  }
}
# erred: fun1()
# warned: fun2()
# success!: fun3()
```

I think you really don't care which it does (error or warning), so you can check for both in one `if` with

```r
if (inherits(res, c("error", "warning"))) {
  ...
}
```

Though I wonder if a warning doesn't always mean "bad" ... over to you if you need some special handling there.

Bringing this back to your case, I'd think you could define

```r
exprs <- c("condition(IndexEvent)", "procedure(IndexEvent)", 
           "visit(IndexEvent)", "drug(IndexEvent)")
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, if you want to keep the types of flaws in a list to browse and sieve out OK functions:

- some example functions:

```
error_and_warning_1 <- \(){
  warning("careful!")
  stop(simpleError("impossible!"))
}

error_and_warning_2 <- \(){
  warning("look out!")
  stop(simpleError("can't do this"))
}

warning_only <- \() simpleWarning("dubious")

OK_function <- \() 42
```

- a name list of functions you want to check:

```
function_names <- list('error_and_warning_1',
                       'warning_only',
                       'error_and_warning_2',
                       'OK_function'
                       )
```

- check:

```
function_names |> 
  Map(f = \(fun) tryCatch(do.call(fun, args = list()),    
                          error = \(e) e,
                          warning = \(w) w
                          ) |> class()
      )
```

`grep`able result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "simpleError" "error"       "condition"  

[[2]]
[1] "simpleWarning" "warning"       "condition"    

[[3]]
[1] "simpleError" "error"       "condition"  

[[4]]
[1] "numeric"
```